# KnockoutJS Mapping not

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have viewmodel with an array of diagnosis codes. In my html I have a button data-bound to a click that adds a blank diagnosis code to the array. This all works.

I use the button to add diagnosis codes. This works.

I am receiving JSON from an external source, and then trying to wrap it in an observable. Because it is from an external source, it does not have functions that I can bind to, so I am binding to functions that are not part of viewModel.

When I try to convert the object back to a JSON string, the new diagnosis codes are empty strings (the default value I add when the new codes).

Here's the code:

```
 <h3>Diagnosis Codes<input type="button" value="Add" data-bind="click:AddDiagnosisCode"/></h3>
    <div data-bind="foreach:DiagnosisCodes">
        <div><input type="text"  data-bind="value:$data"/><input type="button" value="Remove" data-bind="click: function(data, event) { RemoveDiagnosisCode($parent, data, event) }"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function AddDiagnosisCode(item)
        {
            item.DiagnosisCodes.push("");
        }

        function RemoveDiagnosisCode(item, code) {
            item.DiagnosisCodes.remove(code);
        }

        function submitJSON() {
            var test= ko.mapping.toJSON(viewModel); // have also tried ko.toJSON(viewModel)
            alert(test);
        }

        var vm = {
           "DiagnosisCodes": ["2345","6789"]
        };

        var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(vm);     
         ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    </script>
```

So for example, if I click Add and type the code ABCD and then call submitJSON, I see :

```
{
    DiagnosisCodes:["2345","6789",""]
}
```

I am expecting

```
{
    DiagnosisCodes:["2345","6789","ABCD"]
}
```

UPDATE: it looks like the mapping plugin converts arrays of simple types (strings, ints, etc) into observables instead of observableArrays. So I modified (with pax's help) the javascript to convert the string arrays to arrays of objects holding the strings, before calling the mapping. Then when converting to JSON, converting them back:

```
<h3>Diagnosis Codes<input type="button" value="Add" data-bind="click:AddDiagnosisCode"/></h3>
    <div data-bind="foreach:DiagnosisCodes">
        <div><input type="text"  data-bind="value:code"/><input type="button" value="Remove" data-bind="click: $root.RemoveDiagnosisCode"/>
        </div>
    </div>
<button onclick="submitJSON()">Show</button>

function submitJSON() {
            //convert to JS object first
            var test= ko.mapping.toJS(viewModel);
            UnMapCodes(test);

            alert(ko.toJSON(test));
        }

           function Code(code)
        {
            var self=this;
            self.code = code;
        }

        function MapToCodes(obj)
        {
            var codes=[];

            for(var c=0; c<obj.DiagnosisCodes.length; c++)
            {
                codes.push(new Code(obj.DiagnosisCodes[c]));
            }

            obj.DiagnosisCodes=codes;
        }

        function UnMapCodes(obj)
        {
            var codes=[];

            for(var c=0; c<obj.DiagnosisCodes.length; c++)
            {
                codes.push(obj.DiagnosisCodes[c].code);
            }

            obj.DiagnosisCodes=codes;
        }


        var vm = {            
           "DiagnosisCodes": ["2345","6789"]
        };

        vm.AddDiagnosisCode= function (item)
            {
                self=this;
                self.DiagnosisCodes.push(new Code(""));
            };
        vm.RemoveDiagnosisCode= function (code) {
                self=this;
                self.DiagnosisCodes.remove(code);
            };

        MapToCodes(vm);

        var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(vm);     
         ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were several problems with the code, restructured it a bit (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VX9f2/2/):

html:

```
<button data-bind="click:submitJSON">submit json</button>
<h3>Diagnosis Codes<input type="button" value="Add" data-bind="click:AddDiagnosisCode"/></h3>
    <div data-bind="foreach:DiagnosisCodes">
        <div><input type="text"  data-bind="value:code"/><input type="button" value="Remove" data-bind="click: $root.RemoveDiagnosisCode"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

js:

```
var Code = function(code){
    var self = this;
    self.code = ko.observable(code);
}

var VM = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.DiagnosisCodes = ko.observableArray([
        new Code("2345"),
        new Code("6789")]);
    self.AddDiagnosisCode = function() {
        self.DiagnosisCodes.push(new Code(""));
    }

    self.RemoveDiagnosisCode = function(item) {
         self.DiagnosisCodes.remove(item);
    }

    self.submitJSON = function() {
        var test= ko.mapping.toJSON(self.DiagnosisCodes); // have also tried ko.toJSON(viewModel)
        alert(test);
        }

}
       //var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(new VM());     
         ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

For clarity, I replaced the initial ko.mapping usage with constructors. It you still wish to use it, let me know.

Comment: Hi pax, thanks for responding. more background on what I'm trying to do: I am receiving JSON from an external source, which is why I am using the mapping plugin to map it into an observable. That is also why I bind to functions that are not part of viewModel. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Sure, you can get the observable tree from the mapping plugin, and then attach the functions. Do you want me to redo the code to reflect this?

Comment: (Slaps forehead) Had not thought of that - I'll give it a shot

Comment: Still having problems: the observable array appears to correctly keep the number of rows in the array correctly, but the value of the added items is not held - yet the textboxes they are bound to have values.

Comment: OK, update the fiddle with you current code, and I'll try to help you out.

Comment: Updated the code in fiddle - it almost seems as if the mapper is making properties that are arrays of string, into an observable, instead of an observable array.

Comment: I figured out a way, using your Code idea - basically converting the array to an array of Codes before mapping, and then converting them back to an array of strings after grabbing the json. - Thanks for all your help!